# (Android) JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, wcf

My below android code is throwing

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"ID":1,"DisplayName":"Manish","UserName":"manish.parab@hotmail.com"}
>   at AuthenticateUserResult of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be
>   converted to JSONArray

Code:

```
 String response = Common.ExecuteHttpRequest(Url);
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONArray jArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("AuthenticateUserResult");
```

response is string from WCF method.

{"AuthenticateUserResult":{"DisplayName":"Manish","ID":1,"UserName":"manish.parab@hotmail.com"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is right, because "AuthenticateUserResult" value is declared as an element ({}) and not as an array ({}).

To fix this, use getJSONObject method to get the value of "AuthenticateUserResult", like this:

```
String response = Common.ExecuteHttpRequest(Url);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject result =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("AuthenticateUserResult");
```

After that, you can retrieve a child element, like:

```
String mUserName = result.getString("UserName");
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `AuthenticateUserResult` is a JSON Object (it's enclosed in `{}`).

Change that line to this

```java
JSONObject jArray =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("AuthenticateUserResult");
```

Then you can get your data as follows :

```java
String displayName = jArray.getString("DisplayName");
// Etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three workarounds to solve this problem.

1.Use JsonObject. Your WCF server just give it in JsonObject.

```
String response = Common.ExecuteHttpRequest(Url);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("AuthenticateUserResult");
```

2.Use json array as a container

```
String response = Common.ExecuteHttpRequest(Url);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray().put(jsonObject.getJSONObject("AuthenticateUserResult"));
```

3.Edit server to provide `AuthenticationUserResult` into json array. The right format would be as below.

```
{"AuthenticateUserResult":[{"DisplayName":"Manish","ID":1,"UserName":"manish.parab@hotmail.com"}]}
```